# why I can't receive messages through a separate function for my discord bot

Tags: python, discord

```
import discord
import mysql.connector
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())
mylb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user='root',
    password="",
    database="worst")
cursor = mylb.cursor()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')
   
async def spam(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$long'):
       await message.channel.send("spam")
    
client.run('my token')
```

In this code when I type $hello I am successfully getting the output of hello but when I type $long which is in another function I am not able to get the output of spam. Pls help me to resolve my issue. I would be thankfull to you.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a distinct lack of understanding of concepts here.

Typing `$hello` works as it's on the `on_message` function; which with the `@client.event` registers it as a listener for whenever a message is sent in Discord. The library is calling this function and executing your code every time someone sends a message.

With your second command - this is *not* the case. You're not calling the `spam` function anywhere so there's no reason why it should be doing anything. Your code is working exactly as it's written.

It would be better to expand the `on_message` function to contain this functionality:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')
    elif message.content.startswith('$long'):
       await message.channel.send("spam")
```

**HOWEVER**, it's probably better to use some kind of framework (like the commands framework) for what you're trying to do. You haven't mentioned a library - so assuming you're using `discord.py` - then the [docs are here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html). There's functionality built into the library to already parse messages for the given prefix and registered commands (you could register your `hello` and `long` commands) and this would invoke separate functions where you can have your logic rather than trying to do it all yourself in `on_message`.

Perhaps read some tutorials online about Python and making discord bots - there's a couple of fundamental concepts you should get to grips with first.

**EDIT**: If you *really* don't want to use existing frameworks then perhaps something like this:

```py
async def hello(message):
    # do whatever else you want to do in here
    await message.channel.send("Hello!")

async def long(message):
    # do whatever else you want to do in here
    await message.channel.send("spam!")


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await hello(message)
    elif message.content.startswith('$long'):
       await long(message)
```

Comment: I  already know this but I want messages through a separate function for my discord bot as I will add more parameters in function

Comment: Then you should either be looking at the commands framework or look at using slash commands instead. These are systems designed to do what you want it to do.

Comment: ok let me try then

Comment: I have added another solution - this would enable you do what you want to do. But I would recommend looking at the existing functionality in the library.

Comment: your code above is not doing that when I am typing $long and I want the output of spam but I am not getting

Comment: What is happening?

Comment: I just need to move my functions above it worked thanks

Comment: Its is working when I am adding single parameter in long function. but when I add multiple it shows the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251499/discussion-between-mudit-dagar-and-esloman).